# Google Directions API - "Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter.",

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm running the below Google Maps Directions API request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.8495996301,-1.46446203532&destination=53.9236806771,-1.38606898017&waypoints=via:53.8662581183,-1.44997238789%7Cvia:53.8840009077,-1.44013139071%7Cvia:53.8998229922,-1.42836848226%7Cvia:53.9095909181,-1.40235219041&DEPARTURE_TIME=1559541600&key=*APIKEY*

This works fine and gets me journey time results, however, when I add in the traffic_model parameter to get pessimistic journey times as below:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.8495996301,-1.46446203532&destination=53.9236806771,-1.38606898017&waypoints=via:53.8662581183,-1.44997238789%7Cvia:53.8840009077,-1.44013139071%7Cvia:53.8998229922,-1.42836848226%7Cvia:53.9095909181,-1.40235219041&DEPARTURE_TIME=1559541600&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=*APIKEY*

I get the following error:

"Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter."

I've tried placing this parameter in a number of places, but none of them appear to work and all provide the same error as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `departure_time` parameter should be in lowercase :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=53.8495996301,-1.46446203532&destination=53.9236806771,-1.38606898017&waypoints=via:53.8662581183,-1.44997238789%7Cvia:53.8840009077,-1.44013139071%7Cvia:53.8998229922,-1.42836848226%7Cvia:53.9095909181,-1.40235219041&departure_time=1559541600&traffic_model=pessimistic&key=YOUR_API_KEY